# Does Postgres optimize out no-op update calls?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have a table in my database with many (10+) `int4` columns, and I am also developing an application server which updates these values.

My current approach requires multiple round trips, because I do something like this, each as a separate call:

```
UPDATE mytable SET a = a + $2 WHERE id = $1;
UPDATE mytable SET b = b + $2 WHERE id = $1;
UPDATE mytable SET c = c + $2 WHERE id = $1;
UPDATE mytable SET d = d + $2 WHERE id = $1;
UPDATE mytable SET e = e + $2 WHERE id = $1;
```

I was thinking to instead abstract this into a general function which can update any number of columns. Something like this:

```
const EMPTY = {
  a: 0, 
  b: 0, 
  c: 0, 
  d: 0, 
  e: 0
};

let changes = {
  a: +5,
  b: -3,
  ...EMPTY
};
```

And then the database query would be something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET a = a + $2, b = b + $3, c = c + $4, d = d + $5, e = e + $5 WHERE id = $1;
```

My questions are:

1. Is this good practice? Or is there another way to avoid all the round trips and separate calls?
2. Is Postgres smart enough to optimize out the no-op calls? The vast majority of these calls are doing nothing. Like in the above example, `c = c + 0, d = d + 0, e = e + 0`. Are these actually performing writes, or does the query planner disregard it? Is it efficient?

Comment: The database doesn't have a clue how many updates you will send for the same record, hard to optimize. Network latency is also something the database can't optimize for you. And what about concurrency? Multiple updates for a single record will always be slower, but you do benefit a little from caching. But it's still slower then a single update for all columns you want to update.

Comment: So Postgres' query planner / optimizer isn't able to intuit that adding 0 to an integer column is a no-op and can be ignored and not executed? A call that adds `5` to `a` and `-3` to `b`, and `0` to `c`, `d`, and `e` will write to all five columns instead of just the first two?

Comment: A write happens on record-level, not column-level. When an update is done, a new version of the record is created, see MVCC. The old version will become invisible after the commit. You can read about this in these chapters: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

Comment: So does that mean that updating one column is about the same cost as updating 20 columns, since the entire record is cloned regardless?

Comment: Yes - all other things being equal, updating a record takes the same amount of time regardless of the number of columns being updated. Obviously updating one numeric column by adding a fixed value to it would be quicker than updating 20 columns each with the result of different, complex, subqueries

Comment: Also, under any circumstances I can think of, updating a set of columns in one statement will always be faster than the cumulative time taken to update the columns in individual statements

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I'm going to use the single massive update then.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to use the fewest SQL commands necessary to achieve a desired result.

PostgreSQL will create new tuples for each row meeting an `UPDATE`'s selection criteria, even if none of the column values have changed.

Unnecessary updates can be avoided by using checks in the `WHERE` clause to exclude rows where none of the column values would change. Another option is to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to exclude unchanged rows by returning `NULL` for rows where all of the old and new column values match. An advantage of the trigger appoach is that all updates to the table are handled instead of having to include the checks in each `UPDATE`.

Avoiding unnecessary row updates can help keep a database performant by minimizing the number of dead tuples. Only performing necessary updates is also important when the value of audit columns, such as `updated_at`, need to be preseved except when actual changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the number of `UPDATE`s is a very smart idea in PostgreSQL, for which many `UPDATE`s are a particularly hard workload.

PostgreSQL won't skip updates that change nothing (they might trigger a trigger). But there is the system trigger function [`suppress_redundant_updates_trigger()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html#BUILTIN-TRIGGERS-TABLE) which you can use for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Interesting, that paragraph also gives a rationale for the implementation: "*the normal behavior […] always performs a physical row update regardless of whether or not the data has changed. This […] makes updates run faster, since no checking is required, and is also useful in certain cases.*"

Comment: I wonder what those "*certain cases*" are, though. Does it have to do with row-level locking in mvcc?

Comment: The "certain case" could be an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.